# What is the largest possible area that $PQRS$ could have?

Tags: problem-solving

> In a $14\times 18$ rectangle $ABCD$, points $P,Q,R$ and $S$ are chosen, one on each side $ABCD$ as pictured. The lengths $AP, PB, BQ, QC, CR, RD, DS$ and $SA$ are all positive integers and $PQRS$ is a rectangle. What is the largest possible area that $PQRS$ could have?

[image]

[Source](http://prnt.sc/bwfdgs).

I am aware that you can guess and check to solve the question but this is under examination conditions and so theoretically I would want to be able to solve this in under 5 minutes in order to consider this solved in the test. I was wondering if any of you had an inkling of a logical procedural way to solve this question and if so be able to explain it to me! Whoever replies is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote did I do something wrong? .....

Comment: For starters, links to images are strongly discouraged, especially low quality images. I would recommend that you type your posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I really appreciate the edit. Will keep all this in my mind next time!

Comment: @TEKNO Don't mind the haters, there's nothing wrong with your question.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Thanks man! Was bad linking on my part though. Any idea about the question?

Comment: @TEKNO It seems to me that it has to be largest when $AP$ and $DS$ are both equal to one, in which case the answer is $222$

Answer (score 0):

forgive my formatting and such, i don't usually do these.

You can use the *coordinate system*  to solve this.

We have: AP = RC, PB = DR, SD = BQ, AS = QC

Since we have to make sure PQRS is a triangle, we cannot only use guess and check. It would take too long. The product of the slopes of perpendicular lines = -1, so we can use this instead.

[here's the picture of the solution since I have less than 10 reputation right now lol.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkUCO.png)

[image]

Basically, we get slope PS * slope SR = -1
$$\frac{14-y}{18-x}*\frac{y}{-x}=-1$$

Simplify
$$14y-y^2=18x-x^2$$
$$y^2-14y=x^2-18x$$
Then, we can try values of y (or x, whichever you prefer. I used y here.)
if you try y = 1, x would not have an integer value. This goes on until y=5, where you get an integer value for x.
$$5^2-14(5)=x^2-18x$$
$$-45=x^2-18x$$
$$x^2-18x+45=0$$
$$(x-15)(x-3)=0$$
Now, there are 2 values of x (and y). The other value of y is just 14-y, and the other value of x is just 18-x, so it doesn't really matter much.
$$(x,y)=(15,5)$$
You can now find the largest possible area for rectangle PQRS.
$$14*18-2 (\frac{15*5}2-\frac{3*9}2) = 150$$

the answer is 150, yippee!